# Erro ao executar requisição de token de acesso usando Web API Spotify

Tags: javascript, api

Estou seguindo um [tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/howtos/web-app-profile) que ensina a como criar um aplicativo client-side que faz uso da Web API para recuperar informações do usuário e exibir.

Cheguei ao seguinte código:

```js
import getAcessToken from "./getAcessToken";
import redirectToAuthCodeFlow from "./redirectToAuthCodeFlow";

const clientId = '771315a53c91488399694c4bec1ae2eb';
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get('code');

if(!code) {
    redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId)
}else{
    const acessToken = await getAcessToken(clientId, code);
    console.log(acessToken);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Meu perfil Spotify</title>
  <script src="./src/script.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Exiba seus dados de perfil Spotify</h1>

  <section id="perfil">
    <h2>Logado como <span id="displayName"></span></h2>
    <span id="avatar"></span>
    <ul>
        <li>User ID: <span id="id"></span></li>
        <li>Email: <span id="email"></span></li>
        <li>Spotify URI: <a id="uri" href="#"></a></li>
        <li>Link: <a id="url" href="#"></a></li>
        <li>Profile Image: <span id="imgUrl"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </section> 
</body>
</html>
```

A função redirectToAuthCodeFlow:

```js
export default async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) {
    const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
    const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

    localStorage.setItem('verifier', verifier);
    
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("response_type", "code");
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
    params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
    params.append("code_challenge", challenge);

    
    document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`
}

function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
    let text = '';
    let possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
    }
    return text;
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier){
    const data = new TextEncoder().encode(codeVerifier);
    const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(digest)]))
        .replace(/\+/g,'-')
        .replace(/\//g,'_')
        .replace(/=+$/, '');
}
```

A função getAcessToken:

```js
export default async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
    const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.append("code", code);
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("code_verifier", verifier);
    console.log(params);

    const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: params
    });

    const { access_token } = await result.json();
    return access_token;
}
```

Mas quando vou ao navegador:

Ele faz o login e nos redireciona para a página do app, mas o token não está sendo recuperado e vem como undefined, e o fetch falha com o erro:

POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token 400 (Bad Request)